# Hover with Image Alpha Array

Tags: image, html, overlay, alpha

*I need a row of links, where each is in a parallelogram shaped box.
I'm using Divs by the way.
I need each box to be alternately black/white.
I want each box to have a unique hover colour.*

```
<div id="bar2">
    <ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                document.write("<a href='");
                document.write(chapLink[i]);
                document.write("'><li id='li" + i + "' style='background-color:" + chapCol1[i] + "; color:" + chapCol2[i] + "'>");
                document.write(chapter[i]);
                document.write("</li></a>");

                document.write("<img src='paragram");
                document.write(i+1);
                document.write(".png'>");
            };
        </script>
    </ol>



var chapCol1 = new Array();
chapCol1[0] = 'white';
chapCol1[1] = 'black';
chapCol1[2] = 'white';
chapCol1[3] = 'black';
chapCol1[4] = 'white';
```

The array works for filling in most of each shape but, unsurprisingly, doesn't cover it entirely. This has led me to the assumption that I'll need to use a sequence of images, one for every combination of colours resulting from the hover.

Thanks in advance - hope my question is clear,
Harry

Comment: Please write what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so let me try to answer it by feature:
For the parallelogram-shaped box:
If I understand it well, you want alternating blocks of black and white and you want the text color inside these blocks to be unique. I don't understand why you try to insert an image after you closed the `<li>`. I guess you are trying to insert the parallelogram shape into the block, right? 
If you want your `<li>` to be shaped according to your PNG image, I would suggest you to use it as the backgorund image of your block, rather than just inserting it afterward. For that, just write `background-image: your_path/your_image.png;` inside your style attribute of the block. You might need to adjust the size of the block, since the image may be "cut".
For adjusting the size, justo do the following: if, for instance, suppose that your image has width 10 pixels and height 20 pixels, and that you want your block to have the same size as your image. Just write the following on your block's style attribute: `width:10px;height:20px;`
But anyways, I'm still thinking that I didn't completely understand what you want to do.
About your last comment saying that you are no able to fill the entire shape: that is probably because the `li` tag has a default `margin` value, and the `background-color` has no effect on the margin.

For the hover color, just add the following to your divs:
`onmouseover='this.style.color="unique_color_here";' onmouseout='this.style.color="standard_color_here";'`

Hope it helps. If you could better explain what you want exactly it would be great :D
Try to explain what those images you have are exactly, and what you want to do with them.

Comment: Thank you very much - this is a very kind response!

Comment: Ooops - I wasn't specific enough in my question: It's the background color that I'm wanting to change. That's why I've the array etc :D Hope this helps you to understand my question a little better. Thanks so far :D .....

Comment: Oh, it's the background color! I still don't really understand what those images you have are, but you have two options to change the background color: 
1) change the background image on mouseover by doing:
`onmouseover='this.style.backgroundimage="path/image_with_unique_color";' onmouseout='this.style.backgroundimage="path/standard_image";'`
2) change the background color by doing:
onmouseover='this.style.backgroundcolor="unique_color_here";' onmouseout='this.style.backgroundcolor="standard_color_here";'